# Change positioning of element if another element has a class

Tags: jquery

I'm a JS noob and I'm trying to apply `position: fixed;` to my header, but ONLY if my mobile menu is closed (and therefore gets the class "closed" applied to it).

Here's what I got so far, but it doesn't work. Any thoughts on it? Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".mobile_nav").hasClass("closed")) {
    $("#main-header").css({
      'position':'fixed',
      'top': '0',
      'right': '0'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: You code is supposed to be working... But once and on page load. I guess you want it to execute when user closes the nav right ?

Comment: Couldn't you do this with CSS or are they pretty far apart in your markup?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies! The nav is closed by default, and that's when I want it to stay fixed. Once the user opens it, it gets the "opened" class and that's when I want it to go up with the page. I tried doing it with CSS, but I guess since the .mobile_nav is INSIDE the #main-header, it doesn't stay fixed. The reason I wanna do this is because my menu is taller than the viewport, so the user has to be able to scroll down the menu when it's opened.

Comment: @MarcelLopes what you have here works just fine. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oWmYmg

Comment: Post the relevant HTML, because it's not clear just like that... Or if you can share the live link, it would help.

Comment: Thanks guys, and sorry for the lack of info, this is my first post here. Here's the page: http://publishouse.com.br/wp/elorza/. It's intended for mobile only, so please adjust your window to 980px width or less for the .mobile_nav to show. Thanks!

Comment: Actually... JS fails because of `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (`  due to `function() {` on line #133. In the above posted code, you say you have `$(document).ready(function() {` on this line... Which is not the case on your live site.

Comment: Wow, I'm sorry about that, I was so desperate I ended up leaving the wrong code on the site. So I guess this bit of code is working, but how can I revert the positioning change as soon as the user opens the menu and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it using a CSS class...

```
.main-header-when-mobilemenu-expanded{
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

and jQuery would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".mobile_nav").hasClass("closed")) {
    $("#main-header").addClass("main-header-when-mobilemenu-expanded");
  }

  $(".mobile_menu_bar_toggle").on("click",function(){
    $("#main-header").toggleClass("main-header-when-mobilemenu-expanded");
  });

});
```

*You can use a shorter class name ;)

This only is to be clear here.*

Comment: That was it, thank you so much, and thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: So if the answer is working, click on the green checkmark aside the voting arrows to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Done! I also upvoted you but, since I literally signed up today, my votes don´t show.

Comment: lol! No problem! It's just that you need 15 rep. point to upvote... That's no a big deal for me, my reward is that you're happy. Welcome to SO ;)